Setting specific package version in Google Colab
It's a long post but I'll try to make it more clear as possible.
For reproducibility reason, I would like to set up conda environment in Google Colab to use a specific version of some packages.
Based on many similar questions on this forum I followed the following steps:
I install condacolab
!pip install -q condacolab
import condacolab
condacolab.install() # expect a kernel restart

Everythig's OK
import condacolab
condacolab.check()


I download miniconda
!mkdir -p ~/miniconda3
!wget https://repo.anaconda.com/miniconda/Miniconda3-latest-Linux-x86_64.sh -O ~/miniconda3/miniconda.sh
!bash ~/miniconda3/miniconda.sh -b -u -p ~/miniconda3
!rm -rf ~/miniconda3/miniconda.sh

And get the following warning (I don't know if it's an issue)
--2024-04-04 11:36:27--  https://repo.anaconda.com/miniconda/Miniconda3-latest-Linux-x86_64.sh
Resolving repo.anaconda.com (repo.anaconda.com)... 104.16.130.3, 104.16.131.3, 2606:4700::6810:8303, ...
Connecting to repo.anaconda.com (repo.anaconda.com)|104.16.130.3|:443... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 200 OK
Length: 144041912 (137M) [application/octet-stream]
Saving to: ‘/root/miniconda3/miniconda.sh’

/root/miniconda3/mi 100%[===================>] 137.37M   164MB/s    in 0.8s    

2024-04-04 11:36:28 (164 MB/s) - ‘/root/miniconda3/miniconda.sh’ saved [144041912/144041912]

PREFIX=/root/miniconda3
Unpacking payload ...
                                                                                       
Installing base environment...


Downloading and Extracting Packages:


Downloading and Extracting Packages:

Preparing transaction: done
Executing transaction: done
installation finished.
WARNING:
    You currently have a PYTHONPATH environment variable set. This may cause
    unexpected behavior when running the Python interpreter in Miniconda3.
    For best results, please verify that your PYTHONPATH only points to
    directories of packages that are compatible with the Python interpreter
    in Miniconda3: /root/miniconda3

I update the base environment since I got that it should be the way as answered here: Is there a method to run a Conda environment in Google Colab? and newly created conda environments won't last in other cells as commented in this answer: https://datascience.stackexchange.com/questions/75948/how-to-setup-and-run-conda-on-google-colab
!conda env update -n base -f environment.yaml #--prune ## I leave --prune for later since even this doesn't do what I actually want

And it didn't work because I understand I can't downgrade python:
Channels:
 - defaults
 - conda-forge
Platform: linux-64
Collecting package metadata (repodata.json): done
Solving environment: failed

SpecsConfigurationConflictError: Requested specs conflict with configured specs.
  requested specs: 
    - cx_oracle=8.2.1
    - hvac
    - ipykernel=6.2.0
    - jupyter=1.0.0
    - matplotlib=3.4.2
    - mlflow=1.24.0
    - numpy=1.20.3
    - pandas=1.3.2
    - pip
    - plotly=5.11.0
    - python=3.9.7
    - python-pptx=0.6.21
    - scikit-learn=0.24.2
    - scipy=1.7.1
    - seaborn=0.11.2
    - shap=0.39.0
    - sphinx=4.2.0
    - sphinxcontrib-applehelp
    - sphinxcontrib-devhelp=1.0.2
    - sphinxcontrib-htmlhelp=2.0.0
    - sphinxcontrib-jsmath=1.0.1
    - sphinxcontrib-qthelp=1.0.3
    - sphinxcontrib-serializinghtml=1.1.5
    - sqlalchemy=1.4.22
    - xgboost=1.3.3
  pinned specs: 
    - cuda-version=12
    - python=3.10
    - python_abi=3.10[build=*cp310*]
Use 'conda config --show-sources' to look for 'pinned_specs' and 'track_features'
configuration parameters.  Pinned specs may also be defined in the file
/usr/local/conda-meta/pinned.

I also tried with a much simpler environment but still in order to install numpy==1.18.4 I would need to downgrade python.
I then tried to downgrade python to python==3.7.6 following these instructions https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/how-to-downgrade-python-version-in-colab/ and these https://saturncloud.io/blog/how-to-change-python-version-in-google-colab/
So I tried
!sudo apt-get install python3.7
!sudo update-alternatives --install /usr/bin/python3 python3 /usr/bin/python3.7 1
update-alternatives: renaming python3 link from /usr/bin/python3.10 to /usr/bin/python3

And also
!ln -sf /usr/bin/python3.7 /usr/bin/python

But I still get
!python --version
Python 3.10.13

If this may be of help, I notice that I have the following
!which python
/usr/local/bin/python

And
!ls /usr/bin/pytho*
/usr/bin/python   /usr/bin/python3.10-config  /usr/bin/python3.7m      /usr/bin/python3.real /usr/bin/python3  /usr/bin/python3.7         /usr/bin/python3-config

It doesn't need to be with conda, I just need to work with some specific versions of python packages.
UPDATE:
I managed to change python following these instructions:
https://medium.com/the-owl/changing-the-python-version-on-google-colab-245fd510d3ae but then I can't use !pip to install condacolab. Is there another way?
Thanks

For a better experience in modern Jupyter where you have !pip and !conda it should be %pip and %conda. It won't magically make things work here, I suspect; however, it is what modern Jupyter uses and I know the magic versions of the commands were added to Google Colab recently. Sharing the outdated exclamation point used in conjunction with pip and conda is only furthering a bad pattern than can lead to problems because the exclamation point in conjunction with pip install and conda install commands can cause issues as it doesn't insure installation to proper environment.
